# spring boot and google oauth

Tags: google-oauth, spring-boot

I've looked at the Oauth2 workflow on Google's docs and it seems pretty intuitive.  Using a basic servlet I understand how I'd process all the callbacks, but using Spring Boot I'm a little confused by what I need to do if I'm using oauth and the Spring security module.

I found a tutorial [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) describing how to add authentication using a username and password, but I'm not sure if this is the best option for my needs as I mostly want to restrict things in the page and not the page itself.  Anyway, assuming I will need authentication per page how can I set up a user using Oauth?  Looking at the tutorial it appears the security module is doing some magic to get the username/password checked against the in-memory database.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

In the example above I see `configureGlobal` sets up the username/password store to check against.  Does spring boot have hard-coded logic for a username/password that will prevent me from using it for Oauth2?  Should I just ignore this security module and set the user directly using my own handlers?

Comment: How did you configure your project to use oauth with google in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to know who Google thinks your user is, you are happy to handle everything yourself you don't necessarily need Spring Security. There is also a Spring Social Google library [here](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google) that you could use to implement the callbacks.